# Why settings.php does not redirect to homepage so it betrays that the file is in that exact location even if moved by security reasons?

Tags: security

I have checked that `www.example.com/sites/default/settings.php` is reachable via web browser, even if it returns an empty page. What is more strange, in Drupal org webpage, http://www.drupal.org/sites/default/settings.php , it gives a 500 internal server error. Shouldn't the access be prohibited to that folder, or even a redirection made?

This is different to the question [Why is settings.php in the web folder?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187191/why-is-settings-php-in-the-web-folder) , though somehow it completes it.

Comment: See the first comment under the accepted answer (can't see how this isn't a duplicate by the way)

Comment: Sorry but I've read both questions like 6 times each now, they're definitely duplicates in their current state. If this one's different, please edit it to change the question from "Why settings.php is accessible via web?" to what you actually need to know, since the answer to that question is covered well in the other one

Comment: This is all answered in the first comment under the accepted to answer to the duplicate - Drupal is everything-to-everyone out of the box, but you are of course welcome to secure those files any way you see fit. It would be weird for a request for settings.php to redirect to the homepage, so they didn't implement that. Nothing stopping _you_ from doing it on your web server, of course, but not everyone has that level of control, and thus Drupal comes with defaults. You'd have to ask Drupal.org why that that request is serving a 500, Drupal core doesn't do that when installed per instructions

Comment: Ok, I simply was a little shocked when I tried to access directly to the file and didn't get a Forbidden reply or something. I have solved the problem by using a `require_once` for the database connection to an external php file outside the public html folder, so even if I "disconnect" the PHP parser, I cannot access the sensible data.